# Using $.when with JSONP with defined callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, jquery-deferred, .when

I'm building a dashboard where the user adds in a contributors details and then enters data for one or more blogs for that contributor.

Each blog is added to the database through an api call using JSONP. (The JSONP callback function name is required in the request.)  So when the user clicks the Add Blog button, the AddBlog function is called - this does some client side validation and sends the ajax request. It also adds the ajax request to an array.

The callback function cbAddBlog does some more validation based on any errors returned from the server.

So when all of the blogs have been added I want to show a message letting the user know the blog(s) have been saved and to reset the form.

The problem is that the callback functions (cbAddBlog) are executed after the code in $.when..

Does $.when work with JSONP when you have a defined callback function? Or is there something else wrong with my code? Would I need to implement Deferred myself in the callback function for this to work?

```
var errorState = false,
    contributorId = '23',
    addBlogCalls = [];

$("#btnAddBlog").click(function (e) {
    $('#add_contributor section.blog').each(function () {       //call addBlog for each of the users blogs
        addBlog(contributorId, $(this).attr('id'));
    });

    $.when.apply($, addBlogCalls).done(function () {
        console.log("WHEN + errorState: " + errorState);  //This is output to console BEFORE the line in the cbAddBlog callback function
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

addBlog : function (contributorId, blogSection) {
    //client side validation - following is excecuted if there are no errors
    addBlogCalls.push(
       $.ajax({
           url           : (apiRoot + "f=jsonp").trim(),
           dataType      : 'jsonp',
           jsonp         : false,
           jsonpCallback : "cbAddBlog", 
           fail: function (e) {
               console.log("error function");
               console.log(e.message);
           },
           done: function (e) {
               console.log("done function");
               console.log(e.message);
           }
       })
    );
    console.log("Added to addBlogCalls array");
    console.log(addBlogCalls);


}

cbAddBlog : function (data) {
    console.log("cbAddBlog data.result: " + data.result); //Printed to console AFTER line from $.when ??

    //code to check if there are any errors returned from server and display them to user
}
```

Output from console:

```
Added to addBlogCalls array
[Object { readyState=1, setRequestHeader=function(), getAllResponseHeaders=function(), more...}]

Added to addBlogCalls array
[Object { readyState=1, setRequestHeader=function(), getAllResponseHeaders=function(), more...}, Object { readyState=1, setRequestHeader=function(), getAllResponseHeaders=function(), more...}]

WHEN + CD.config.errorState: false

cbAddBlog data.result: 1
cbAddBlog data.result: 1
```

I see the same issue (callback being executed AFTER $.when even when there is only one blog..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.when()` does not accept an array as an argument, it requires one or more promises as individual arguments.  So, if you have an array, you need to use `.apply()` to get that array turned into individual arguments.  Change this:

```
$.when(addBlogCalls)
```

to this:

```
$.when.apply($, addBlogCalls)
```

---

It also appears that all your overriding of the JSONP callback is preventing jQuery from processing the result and thus it can't resolve the promise so `$.when()` doesn't work.  Since you have now changed your server to accept `callback=fname`, this is easier because you can remove all your special JSONP handling and let jQuery do what it wants to do.  Your code can also be cleaned up to not rely on globals that are not reinitialized for successive operations.

I'd recommend something like this:

```
$("#btnAddBlog").click(function (e) {
    var addBlogCalls = $('#add_contributor section.blog').map(function () {       //call addBlog for each of the users blogs
        return addBlog(contributorId, $(this).attr('id'));
    }).toArray();

    $.when.apply($, addBlogCalls).done(function () {
        console.log("WHEN + errorState: " + errorState);  //This is output to console BEFORE the line in the cbAddBlog callback function
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});


addBlog : function (contributorId, blogSection) {
    //client side validation - following is excecuted if there are no errors
    return $.ajax({
           url           : (apiRoot + "f=jsonp").trim(),
           dataType      : 'jsonp'
    }).done(cbAddBlog);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that - much appreciated - I've updated that in my code. However now its not executing the code in the when section at all.. Could this be something to do with the fact that this is JSONP? I'm using similar code for JSON calls elsewhere and it works perfectly - once the calls are complete it executes the code in $when.

Comment: @user1492058 - In general it's a bad thing to specify your own callback function for jQuery JSONP calls because you are cutting jQuery out of the response loop so it can't do the things it normally does when the response is received (such as resolve promises or call completion callbacks).  So, that is probably why you aren't getting any resolved promises.

Comment: @user1492058 - This part of the jQuery doc is not very clear, but if your server requires `cb=xxx` in the URL instead of `callback=xxx`, then there should be a way to tell jQuery to just change the name of the callback parameter, but still let it supply it's own function so it can do all its normal response processing.  My first guess from reading the doc (which is poorly written in this regard) is that you can set the `jsonp: 'cb'` option for `$.ajax()`, take the `cb=cbAddBlog` out of the URL and then process the ajax response in a normal jQuery place, perhaps at the end of `$.when()`.

Comment: Thank you for that. I've just updated the code above. From the docs (api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) it sounds like I need to set jsonp to false and add the function name in the jsonpCallback param. It's still not doing the trick tho. The response comes back wrapped in a function called 'callback' and its not reaching either the fail or done functions in ajax. Adding the code for the callback at the end of $.when wouldn't work tho - I only want the code in $.when to be executed when all the addBlog calls are completed - there could be multiple calls to add blog data for a contributor..

Comment: @user1492058 - I'm not sure you understand the issue I was describing.  If you provide your own callback function for the JSONP call (which you are doing), then jQuery does NO processing of the response.  No ajax callbacks are called, no promises are resolved.  jQuery is never even told about the response.  So, you get no functionality from jQuery on the response.  You would have to do everything yourself.

Comment: @user1492058 - one more read of the jQuery docs, suggests you can just put `cb=?` into the URL and remove both the `jsonp: false` and  `jsonpCallback: "cbAddBlog"` arguments.  That should let jQuery generate it's own callback function, process the response, resolve the promises and get `$.when()` triggered.  You can then call `cbAddBlog()` either in the individual promise, in a success handler for each ajax call or in `$.when()` for each item.

Comment: Thanks for your time and patience on this. We've changed it on the server side so it takes callback=cbAddBlog. In the ajax I have ''dataType: 'jsonp',
jsonpCallback : 'cbAddBlog'' The response is wrapped in the function name. Is that correct? It does call get into the ajax success function now but still not getting to the $.when. I understand what you mean about overriding JSONPs implementation by specifying a function - just not sure how to structure this so I don't do that.. Latest code here: JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k89s0qca/

Comment: @user1492058 - now that your server accepts callback, get rid of all ajax arguments that have anything to do with JSON other than `dataType: 'jsonp',`.  Let jQuery manage the entire thing and just call you when it's done.  That will let it do everything it wants to do.  `cbAddBlog()` should be called by jQuery, not as the callback directly.  There are multiple ways you can ask the Ajax call to call `cbAddBlog()` when the ajax results are available.  I will add one way to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much - that works now. And great to know that $.when works with jsonp. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @user1492058 - yeah.  Finally got it.